# Python - Mechanize post form asp webforms

Tags: python, mechanize

This is a some information about the form:

```
<form1 POST http://www.example./something application/x-www-form-urlencoded
..............
<RadioControl(divPolls$rlPolls=[836, 837])>
<ImageControl(divPolls$btnVote=)>
```

Now the input button name is `divPolls$btnVote`.

My code is:

```
b = mechanize.Browser()
b.open(URL)

b.select_form(nr=0)
b.form['divPolls$rlPolls'] = ['837']

b.submit()
```

The problem is, when i print the response, I get to a different page. so the `b.submit()` is submitting through another button which directs to the log in page.

How am i able to solve it by making Mechanize submit through `divPolls$btnVote`

Comment: Your "information about the form" isn't even close to anything resembling valid HTML.

Comment: it's now from HTML source, just from mechanize printing the form.

Comment: Which button was the one that the user clicked is transmitted as a new POST parameter with a value that's usually meaningless. Try doing `b.form['divPolls$btnVote']=''`. (That said, I'd recommend driving a real browser to automate ASP.NET Web Forms, using something like WATIR or PhantomJS.)

Comment: It didn't work i added it before submitting but same issue.

Comment: I'm getting redirected to another page.

Comment: Ok then, I noticed Mechanize don't do javascript. You have any solution ?

Comment: As I said. WATIR, PhantomJS, Selenium, some other way of driving a real browser from a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mechanize doesn't support Javascript.

Other solutions that support javascript:

- Watir
- PhantomJS
- Selenium